# Rotating curves around an origin in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have two curves which meet around origin z and y, listed below. When I plot these according to certain functions I get the attached plot.

```
origin_z = 260
origin_y = 244

plt.plot(phi_z+origin_z,phi_y+origin_y,'b')
plt.plot(phi_z+origin_z,phi_y+origin_y,'r')
```

[image]

Where phi_z and _y are some functions (which I have avoided posting for the sake of clarity). I want to rotate both lines about 45 degrees clockwise around the specified origin, but when I try the following code, it merely shifts the curves further along each axis rather than rotating them:

```
phi_z_rot = origin_z + np.cos(45) * (phi_z - origin_z) - np.sin(45) * (phi_z - origin_z)
phi_y_rot = origin_y + np.cos(45) * (phi_y - origin_y) - np.sin(45) * (phi_y - origin_y)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Sorry for not posting more of the functions, but hopefully it isn't necessary.

Comment: *"..I have avoided posting for the sake of clarity"* contradicts [mcve]. If those are not important, leave them out completely, or if they are important, show them in a simplified manner. But make sure the problem is reproducible. You cannot expect people guessing which variable is used for which purpose a what position of the actual code you have a problem with. I guess, once you provide such a [mcve], you can get an answer quite quickly.

Comment: As an addendum to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, avoiding posting *unrelated* code is generally a good idea which you just took a bit too far.

Comment: Possibly, you may also just revisit [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). Your rotation matrix is not even a matrix here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without much information is very little what I can explicitly provide. Anyhow, you have your rotation wrong. First the angles are in degrees instead of radians, and then you use the incorrect rotation matrix.

Avoiding the translation of the coordinates, the proper rotation is as follows:

```
rot = np.pi/4
phi_z_rot = phi_z*np.cos(rot)+phi_y*np.sin(rot)
phi_y_rot = -phi_z*np.sin(rot)+phi_y*np.cos(rot)
```